# .NET component for Math ML which can edit formulas, render them as image

Tags: c#, mathml

At the moment the most popular component MathML.Net is not available for download, I am wondering if there are other .Net components that can help with this issue (can edit formulas, render them as image)

Answer (score 1):

I found ["gNumerator"](http://numerator.sourceforge.net/) just moments ago, which should render MathML, and it's written in C# for Winforms. I haven't tried using this on my own, but the screenshots look promising.