# Trignometric / mathematical expressions on windows form in .NET

Tags: .net, windows, trigonometry

I am developing an application in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) Windows for mathematics. I want to show these expressions:

[image]

Which font do I have to use and how do I display these?

Comment: Not an answer, but i guess Latex does something similar: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX , may be you can integrate it in your app

Comment: @Madhur: LaTeX uses [TeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX). Not sure how easily *that* will be to integrate into WinForms. [MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML) might be a better way to go, but you're still left with quite a bit of work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NET component for Math ML which can edit formulas, render them as image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862250/net-component-for-math-ml-which-can-edit-formulas-render-them-as-image)

Comment: these all links are only direct to wiki. i need atleast usable form in my application. from where i can get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved by this by following [The Code Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Code_Project) article *[Enable Your Users to Write Math Equations in Your Web and Desktop Apps](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Eq2Img.aspx)*.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Cambria Math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambria_%28typeface%29) Microsoft uses it in Microsoft Word Equations.

To use it my guess is (I haven't tried it) that WPF might give you the best odds as it supports open types.

Comment: Thanks Erno, but it is not some how helpful for me. I am using this , which sounds fine : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Eq2Img.aspx

Comment: I didn't know this project and web service. Nice! Unfortunately it requires the user to use yet another expression language to enter an equation.

Comment: I fail to see how this is helpful at all - how do you display anything that can't already be rendered using Unicode with this font?