# Render Symbols in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, math

I need to represent a variety of symbols (mathematics, physics etc) in a WPF application.

Is there any way to read text in a special format and convert it into equations or symbols that can be displayed on a WPF Canvas?

Thank you.

Comment: using custom manipulation yes, but native wpf does not have any support for such interpretations.

Comment: There is a project called [WPF-Math](https://launchpad.net/wpf-math) which does exactly what you need, however, it hasn't been in active development for a few years.

Comment: Thanks @pushpraj; could you please provide tips on this?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9719934/87399) has a way to get MathML to display in a WPF WebBrowser.

Comment: Thanks @icemanind; I checked WPF-Math already but it is not supported anymore; please do you know of alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is roll my own, and its not hard to do. [STIX font's](http://www.stixfonts.org/) has 1700+ math and engineering symbols in the form of a font, and its a free font. You can download a [TTF port from here](https://sites.google.com/site/olegueret/stixfonts-ttf). What you'll want to do is embed the font inside your application. [This blog](http://www.siao2.com/2005/11/20/494829.aspx) will teach you how to do this. Finally, creating some kind of markup to map text to the appropriate symbol. For example `{PI}` could map to the unicode character in the font that shows the PI symbol. Install the font on your computer, then you can go to [this page](http://www.stixfonts.org/allGlyphs.html) to see all the glyphs and what Unicode character they map to. So an example of your mapping function might look like this:

```
private string MarkupToUnicode(string markup)
{
    markup = markup.Replace("{PI}", "\U000003D6");
    markup = markup.Replace("{PHI}", "\U000003D5");

    return markup;
}
```

This will correctly map the PI symbol and PHI symbol, according to [this page](http://www.stixfonts.org/allGlyphs.html). Of course, you'll have to add extra symbols that you plan to use (and yes, I know its a tedious task)

So once you have your function that replaces your markup code with the appropriate Unicode replacements, set that text to a TextBlock object, set the FontFamily property of your TextBlock to your embedded STIX font, then place the TextBlock on your canvas and viola!

Answer (score -1):

When you want "special characters or symbols" you should probably use images instead of depending on fonts.

I would suggest to look for such symbols as images and use them in your WPF Canvas.

Answer (score -1):

If you have vector representaion of this symbols you can easily convert it to WPF Path (or Geometry) object, so it can be used on WPF forms.

Comment: **easily**  ...? Don't think this answers the question