# Using Math Symbols in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, math, richtextbox

Upon looking at Word it has this Equations which can be added and modified in the document, I need to be able to do the same in my program, that is allow adding/modifying of math equations although I am not sure how to proceed. What I am contemplating to do is to be able to open Word in my program and let the user enter their equations and upon saving those equations should be seen in my textbox or richtextbox, I have not yet investigated on how could I proceed with my plan but that is what I am planning to do for now.

Or is there any other control out there that I could use that supports adding math equations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899204/how-to-render-a-formula-in-wpf-or-winforms

Comment: Thanks for the link. What i am doing now is leveraging the power of Word in Equations so I need not worry any more in looking for text editors with equation capability. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use NuGet packege WPF-Math. You can write latex formulas.