# Display equation to mathematical format

Tags: c#, math, mathematical-optimization

I'm working on an equation editor, and I’m trying to display equation to mathematical format, but I have no idea. 
The editor work with a Dictionary. Users complete a textbox like that:

```
m*R/cos(3)-mAir^(6)
```

And another textbox with the c# code is automatically completed

```
m*R/Math.Cos(3)-Math.Pow(mAir,6)
```

I want to create another textbox (or image or other thing) with the math format

I search a lot and I don't found any free solution .

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "math format" if it would be in a text box?

Comment: I suggest using google and searching for open source formula editor. You should find plenty of examples.

Comment: By "math format" i mean [something like that](https://imageshack.us/scaled/large/339/formule.png)

Comment: Perhaps [How to render a formula in WPF or WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8899204/1468366) answers your question? If so, I'd suggest closing this question here as a duplicate.