# How to draw an equation better?

Tags: wpf, draw

I have a code that takes an equation and draws it by using points. For example, if the equation is y=ax^2+b*x+1 - than I will go over the x's from -100 to 100, find their matching Y value and hold a list of points. This is part of my code inside a loop. My window height is 800 and it's width is 800, so for the point (0,0) I put a small Elipse by setting Canvas.SetTop(e1,400) and Canvas.SetLeft(e1,500) and so on. For each point of the equation I put a small elipse on the Canvas to draw the equation.

How can draw the equation better in WPF to get smooth lines, and not a dotted graph?

```
 Ellipse E1 = new Ellipse();
 E1.Width = 5;
 E1.Height = 5;
 E1.Fill = Brushes.Black;
 double y;
 y = Exp1;
 y = y / 5;
 x = x / 5;
 x = x + 500.0;
 y = 400.0 - y;
 Canvas.SetTop(E1, y);
 Canvas.SetLeft(E1, x);
 Can1.Children.Add(E1);
```

Comment: Use the [Polyline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polyline.aspx) control and add data points to its `Points` property.

Comment: I don't think it is available in raw .NET but look for cubic spline for smooth curve. If you have enough points the Polyline should look smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw any shape that you need with the [`Path` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That includes a variety of curves that are really quite easy to use, once you know what each parameter is for. You can find an introductory article that explains the basics in the [Shapes and Basic Drawing in WPF Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN. You can find more drawing examples in the first linked page.

One thing to note is that you'd probably find it a lot easier to define your mathematical symbols using Blend and then use the auto generated XAML, rather than trying to compose it all in C#.

If you don't want to draw it all yourself, you can find a number of alternative solutions, such as third party libraries and controls, listed in the most popular answer to the [How to render a formula in WPF or WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899204/how-to-render-a-formula-in-wpf-or-winforms) question here on StackOverflow.