# XAML - Display formatted ComboBoxItems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF app. In this app, I have a ComboBox. The ComboBox display a list of algabra formulas. I want my students to be able to choose a formula. The formulas include superscripts. For that reason, I think I need to use a TextBlock like this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run>x</Run>
    <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript">2</Run>
    <Run>+ 2xy </Run>
</TextBlock>
```

I am putting those formulas in

```
public class Formula
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Formula(string text) 
    {
        this.Text = text;
    }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel() 
    {
        this.Formulas = new List<Formula>
        {
            new Formula("<TextBlock><Run>x</Run><Run Typography.Variants=\"Superscript\">2</Run><Run>+ 2xy </Run></TextBlock>"),
            new Formula("<TextBlock><Run>x</Run><Run Typography.Variants=\"Superscript\">3</Run><Run>+ 3xy </Run></TextBlock>")
        };
    }  
}
```

I am then trying to display those formulas, formatted, as ComboBoxItems. Currently, I have the following:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Formulas}" DisplayMemberPath="Text" />
```

This approach does not show the formulas formatted. Is there a way to bind ComboBoxItems to show formatted values? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: You would need to set the `Inlines` property of a TextBlock in the `ItemTemplate` of the ComboBox. Unfortunately that property isn't bindable, but there are workarounds explained here on StackOverflow. Search for "wpf bind textblock inlines".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to look into libraries that offer proper display of formulas (a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899204/how-to-render-a-formula-in-wpf-or-winforms))

Although if you want to make this approach work you can do it the following way.

```
<Window x:Class="BindFormulas.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindFormulas"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:XamlTextToObjectConverter x:Key="XamlTextToObjectConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Formulas}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="local:Formula">
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Text, Converter={StaticResource XamlTextToObjectConverter}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The converter that will convert the XAML text to actual objects:

```
public class XamlTextToObjectConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly Regex Regex = new Regex("(<.*?)>(.*)(</.*?>)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var xamlText = value as string;

        if (xamlText != null)
        {
            var xamlTextWithNamespace = Regex.Replace(xamlText, "$1 xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">$2$3");
            try
            {
                return XamlReader.Parse(xamlTextWithNamespace);
            }
            catch (Exception) // catch proper exceptions here, not just Exception
            {
                return value;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

[image: end result]

Again, probably you'd be better off with a library that does this properly :)

This approach is wrong for multiple reasons:

The `Formula` class probably shouldn't know about things like `TextBlock` and `Run`. That's not a model class's concern.
Also I'm sure you can provide a XAML string that will trip this converter up.

That said, if this will be a very simple app, where you will be a 100% sure that the XAML strings can be properly converted, then maybe this approach is OK as well.

Comment: I tried to integrate this approach. Unfortunately, I just got XAML strings. I didn't get actual superscripts etc.

Comment: There must be something strange going on then, because it works on my end. If you set a breakpoint in the `catch` of the converter, does it stop there?