# How to display mathematical formulas in C# Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

How I can display mathematical formulas in C# Windows Forms like this from image?
[image: Formula]

Comment: Did you even try **anything**? Just a second of searching lead me to this, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899204/how-to-render-a-formula-in-wpf-or-winforms

Comment: I have already checked that but I didn't find any that can be used as library

Comment: The top answer lists a number of libraries.

Answer (score 1):

There are some existing packages in .Net like:

https://github.com/verybadcat/CSharpMath

https://github.com/ForNeVeR/wpf-math

http://www.forkosh.com/mathtex.html

Just do a quick google for 'C# package to draw math formulas' and u will find plenty of them

Comment: None of this libraries is for Windows Forms

Comment: There is CSharpMath.Forms from CSharpMath but that is for Xamarin