# how to put math symbols in text in visual studio?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm going to make a calculator with C#, and I want to put special characters and math symbols in the name of button, how do I do it? I use Visual Studio 2022 - Windows form.
[image]

Comment: Note that Visual Studio is the program you use to author your code. Your question is actually about C#/WinForms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render a formula in WPF or WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899204/how-to-render-a-formula-in-wpf-or-winforms)

Comment: They are not text.  Use the button's Image property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two principal methods you can use:

1. Use a unicode symbol, if one exists
2. Custom painting

The might be 3rd party components out there that allow you to use markup like HTML to format the contents, which might make nr. 2 easier.

For unicode symbols, do a search for "unicode square root symbol" and similar and you'll find symbols such as:

- √ which is U+221A, which you can use in C# with `"\u221a"`
- ∛, U+221B, or `"\u221b"`
- ... and so on

To do custom painting, you probably need to find a button component that allow you to add painting code without having to paint the entire button from scratch. I'd say go with the unicode approach if you can.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try `button.Text = "test\u????";`

or you could just past them as string `button1.Text = "क";`